# for (String s : letters) {JAVA} How is this in php? for ($string_l1: $array){PHP}?

Tags: java, php, arrays, for-loop

I have a question I hope I can help, newly start "programing" with php, java used before but did not think my language is not, well that's another topic ..

I have this code in java

```
String str = "c, o, d, e";
List<String>=Arrays.asList letters(str.splir(","));
Collections.shuffle(letters);
String outout = "";
for(String s:letters){output += s;} 
System.out.println(output);
```

This works and I messed up the lyrics, creating a new string with the letters jumbled

Now I want to do the same in php, but I have no idea how
This is used in php for (String s: letras_)

```
$string_letters = "c,o,d,e";
$array = explode(",",$string_letters);
suffle($array);
$string_output = "";
for($string_letters:$array){$string_output += $string_letters;}
echo $string_output;
```

but this does not work, any ideas? Thank you :)

Comment: The PHP [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) is a bit different.

Comment: You might want to use `shuffle()` instead of `suffle()`.

Comment: in real code i use shuffle() just grammatical error, but still dont works

Comment: Instead of using foreach, you could use the opposite of explode... `$string_output = implode('', $array);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would want to use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and also change the `+=` to `.=` as we are appending a string

```
$string_letters = "c,o,d,e";
$array = explode(",",$string_letters);
shuffle($array); // <- i assume 'suffle' was a spelling mistake
$string_output = "";

foreach ($array as $char)
{
    $string_output .= $char;
}

echo $string_output;
```

as explained in the link above the foreach will go though every value in `$array` setting it to the variable `$char` for use within your loop in that iteration. you then append `$char` to your `$string_output`

you could reuse `$string_letters` instead of `$char` but my personal preference is to use a new variable(s) when iterating using a loop so it's easier to understand when you read the code (as `$char` has not been used anywhere else there's no confusion of it's value)

2 other methods to do this is to determine the size of the array and use the [for loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) `for($i = 0; $i > $arraysize; $i++)` or inside a [while loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) use `if($i > $arraysize){break;}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried your code and get a "0" :/

Comment: @erozz my bad, in PHP you also need to use .= not += to append strings. this is what happens to your mind when you code with both PHP and Javascript at the same time, the operators get mixed up